# Which country would employ foreign air traffic controllers?

Tags: air-traffic-control

Air traffic controllers from Pakistan hold ICAO approved Licences (ATCL).
Which other country will accept this ATCL for employment acceptance?

Answer (score 0):

As I know, Vietnam is one of the countries employing foreigners for the position of an air traffic controller.